# When calling original version of DLL hooked function, I get infinite recursion

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I want to override part of a functionality of certain winapi function, `SetWindowPos`. I'm only trying to prevent any Z axis operations - putting windows behind or on top. My basic pseudocode idea was:

```
bool NewSetWindowPos(zaxis_argument, ...) {
  return OldSetWindowPos(NULL, ...);
}
```

I use Mhook library and it works perfectly.

The implementation is a little bit clumsy, as I'm casting variables to functions which always looks weird:

```
//Get the function refference for overriding with mhook
PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION OriginalSetWindowPos = 
  (PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)::GetProcAddress( 
  ::GetModuleHandle( L"user32" ), "SetWindowPos" );
```

I define a type that follows the original function argument count:

```
//Define type for the original SetWindowPos function
typedef BOOL(*SetWindowPos_type)(
  _In_      HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  _In_      int X,
  _In_      int Y,
  _In_      int cx,
  _In_      int cy,
  _In_      UINT uFlags
);
```

And here's my new function:

```
BOOL WINAPI
HookedSetWindowPos(
  _In_      HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  _In_      int X,
  _In_      int Y,
  _In_      int cx,
  _In_      int cy,
  _In_      UINT uFlags
  ) {
  //The |SWP_NOZORDER adds flag that instructs the function to ignore any Z-order operations.
  //Ther than Z-order functionality is still available, I just pass the original arguments
  return ((SetWindowPos_type)OriginalSetWindowPos)(hWnd, 0, X, Y, cx, cy, uFlags|SWP_NOZORDER);
}
```

I hook that function on DLL init:

```
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      //Override function
      Mhook_SetHook( (PVOID*)&OriginalSetWindowPos,  HookedSetWindowPos );
      //Force create console window
      createConsole();
      break;
```

The problem is that `OriginalSetWindowPos` somehow maps to `HookedSetWindowPos`. Once `SetWindowPos` is called, `HookedSetWindowPos` calls `OriginalSetWindowPos` which is actually `HookedSetWindowPos` too - and that loops forever, or at least until the process crashes due to stack overflow.

**Q**: How do I call original function after I have hooked a function in DLL?

Comment: Where do you obtain the reference to the original address? It seems the pointer stored in that part is overwritten when hooked. Also, why are you using `PNT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION `? Why not use SetWindowsPos_type OriginalSetWindowPos

Comment: @TheDutchMan I started with someone elses code. Eventually, I discovered that I can use `SetWindowsPos_type` directly. Why would that pointer be overwritten? And if it is, where's the original function?

Comment: @Tomáš Zato Have you solved your problem? I have similar one with mhook

Comment: @SanjaMelnichuk No I have not solved it. My DLL injection file still has that part commented out waiting for solution.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, to help you solve this I'll show you this code. This is the type definition of the original function, I've named it `oSetWindowPos`, underneath it is the soon to be hooked function `hSetWindowPos`.

```
BOOL(__stdcall WINAPI *oSetWindowPos)(
   _In_      HWND hWnd,
   _In_opt_  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
   _In_      int X,
   _In_      int Y,
   _In_      int cx,
   _In_      int cy,
   _In_      UINT uFlags
) = SetWindowPos;

BOOL __stdcall WINAPI hSetWindowPos(HWND hWnd, HWND hWnd_ia, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, UINT uFlags)
{
     OutputDebugStringA(" - Inside setwindowpos trampoline..");
     return oSetWindowPos(hWnd, hWnd_ia, x, y, cx, cy, uFlags);
}
```

I have not yet used the MHook library, although I Googled it and came across a [basic example of hooking in MHook](http://codefromthe70s.org/mhook22.aspx). It seems that MHook works the same as MS Detours (which is the library I've used).

```
void Hook() {
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    if (DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)oSetWindowPos, hSetWindowPos) == NO_ERROR)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA(" - setwindowpos succesfully hooked");
    }
    DetourTransactionCommit();
}
```

Now as I said before I have not yet used MHook so it might be a problem on their side, but if you insist on using MHook need to use the following code in order to hook the function:

```
BOOL bHook = Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&oSetWindowPos, hSetWindowPos);
```

Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: I upvote now and accept if it works. Thank you very much for your effort.